# for loops in objects vs in arrays

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript for…in vs for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242841/javascript-for-in-vs-for)
>   [difference between for..in and for loops, and counter declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949504/difference-between-for-in-and-for-loops-and-counter-declaration)

Is there any particular reason that for loops in arrays should be coded like `for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {` whereas loops in objects are just `for (var i in foo) {` Is it because of how objects are set up vs how arrays are set up? (I know arrays are a type of object btw) or just another nitpicky programming convention.

Comment: actually that's not a good duplicate, so I'll look for one of the 8 billion other ones ...

Comment: Little half-baked xample: http://jsfiddle.net/XCrUx/

Comment: The question itself [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992295/correct-use-of-a-for-in-loop-in-javascript) is not much of an overlap, but the inestimable T.J.Crowder's answer covers all the bases.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I don't know if I'm misunderstanding this but http://w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp says (or implies) that arrays are a type of object...

Comment: @Kpower yes arrays are objects, but they're special, and [please be careful with w3schools](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: @MaVRoSCy how exactly aren't arrays a type of object..?

Comment: @Pointy so should I stick to MDN from now on ;)

Comment: @Kpower ha ha well yes MDN tends to be a lot better, plus it's basically a Wiki so if you find an error you can fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the main reason is because `for...in` only iterate over defined members.

So,

```
var arr = [];
arr[10] = "hi";
for(var x in arr)
{
    alert(x);
}
```

will only show the one value that *is* defined. Sometimes this is a good thing-- usually not.

Also, `for...in` loops over properties, not array indices (in javascript an array is just an a regular object with properties whose names are the values you assign to the array)

So when you use for..in you can get weird results, like:

1

2

3

length

toString

etc.

Using the typical `for` syntax is just the better option for arrays. With objects, the `for...in` makes more sense, since the undefined issues don't come up as often. Either way, I like to use the `for(var x; x < y; x++)` syntax, though. It just feels better in js.

Comment: Not "in the past", a for..in loop iterates over all **enumerable** properties of an object, including those on its `[[Prototype]]` chain. The numeric indices of an Array are just numeric object properties that are treated differently by Array methods.

Comment: It's not weird behaviour, it's expected.

Comment: @Aesthete and being expected means it can't also be weird?

Comment: @RobG and yeah, I know. Probably not the best wording on my part, but believe it or not I did have the right idea

Answer (score 2):

You should use `for(i=0; i<n; i++)` looping when you are iterating a **list**, as they are **indexable by integer**.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]; // arr[0] == 1; arr[1] == 2;
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { alert(arr[i]; } // 1, 2, 3, 4
```

You should use the `for...in` looping when you are iterating an **object**, as it is **indexable by key**. If you think about an object as a **key:value map**. Remember to check if the object **has it's own property matching each key**, as the `in` statement will check down the object's **proptotype chain** and return property names inherited from above.

```
obj = { 
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
}
for(key in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key);       // foo, bar
    alert(obj[key]);  // 1, 2
  }
}
```